# FEET TRACKING using i phone camera

Tags: iphone

I saw that someone has made an app that tracks your feet using the camera, so that you can kick a virtual football on your iPhone screen.

how is this done?what technlogy do they use ,can anyone update me something about this.how do the iphone juggles the ball on touching feet? any help is appreciated.thankx in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you track motion using the iPhone's camera?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933716/how-can-you-track-motion-using-the-iphones-camera)

Answer (score -1):

It's motion tracking. The camera senses when the foot hits the virtual ball.